# Use case diagram: actor with more permissions

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

Regarding Use-Case Diagram:
Consider 2 kinds of actors: Customer & User. Customer is a User (generalization)
I want to model the use case of a Search option for items ('search items') which is allowed for all users **without the need for a login** : but only a customer (because he is registered) could take part in the use case **add items**. note that this means that the customer will also need to be logged in for this to happen.
I can't seem to make it work without messing up the whole diagram.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a constraint to the use case. You can make that visible in a diagram by using a constraint element which looks like a note but has the text enclosed in curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted in the [specs](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/):

> NOTE. An Actor does not necessarily represent a specific physical entity but instead a particular role of some entity that is
>   relevant to the specification of its associated UseCases. Thus, a single physical instance may play the role of several different
>   Actors and, conversely, a given Actor may be played by multiple different instances.

Thus there is no reason to try to mash multiple use cases into single Actor; User and Customer represents two different roles and thus it is often better to represent it by two actors; the fact that Customer is derivation of User can represented by ­a generalization.

And finally you can add a note to the use-case association to specify that the Customer has to be logged in - but at least for me this seems unnecessary, because the User already had to log in in order to take on the "Customer" role.

[image]

Comment: you can add a use case: authenticate with an include relationship

Comment: I showed this diagram to my lab instructor for such problem, she scolded me for coming up with such a studiously wrong syntax.